# How to connect to database with Visual Studio 2017 in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm currently using Visual Studio Community2017, and I created a Windows Form, but I'm having a problem when I come to connecting my Windows Form to a Database.

I was using Visual Studio 2013 before, and I remember that to connect to a SQL Database, I just had to install an extension to my project, and then I could use the library of MySQL. 
But in the 2017, I can't find the same thing.

I tried to follow the instructions of the .NET tutorial on Microsoft's website, but didn't manage to make it work properly, I didn't understand all the steps.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks a lot :)

I already used MySQL with PHPMyAdmin with Eclipse.

Comment: probably this was what you used to let your application connect to a MySQL DB. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ I googled "MySQL C#" and it was the second link. Not hard to find. There are tutorials available too on the same result page.

Comment: I already tried this and didn't manage to make it work. 
I'll try again though.

Thanks

Comment: No problem. If you still can't make it work, post a question here containing the specific code you've written and any errors you're experiencing and people will be able to help you in more detail. As it stands this question is too vague to give a proper answer to.

Comment: My problem is : I can't find what to import to work with MySQL in my code. I connected my database, but now I want to work with it, and I still don't find it..
I want to use the " Connection " thing, like as if I wrote "using MySQL.something.something "

Comment: sorry but I've no idea what you mean. Have you followed any of the tutorials suggested by the google search? Seems like you need to get the basics straight before you continue.

Comment: I did.
My Database is connected to my Windows Form Application on Visual Studio.
But, the problem now is that I want to use my Database in my functions, in my code. But I can't find what to do. 
I know that on Eclipse I have to write " import java.mysql.* " for example, and on Visual Studio 2013 I wrote " using MySQL ". 
But on Visual Studio 2017 nothing of this seems to work, that's my problem, I followed every tutorials I found, but nothing dealt about this.

Comment: well then a good tutorial will show you how to work with the database (by this, I assume you mean write queries to select/insert/update/delete your data and read the results).

Comment: I guess you're looking for string connectionString = "stuff"; SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString) Afterwards you get your using(conn){} block

Comment: Yes, it's something like this. 
I want to work with my Database in my code, but I can't, because I have nothing imported.

Comment: "I have nothing imported". You mean you need to add a reference to the MySQL DLL into your project? Again you seem to lack some basic knowledge of .NET applications. Feels like you are maybe running before you can walk.

Comment: Yep, I need to add something to my .NET application. 
I know we can add some packages, and I think I need to add a package to my project to use these functions.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation.html gives you the different ways to install it. Either you can download it to your computer (in which case you add the DLL as a reference) or you can add the MySQL Nuget repository to Visual Studio and install the package into your project. You can easily google how to do either of those processes (in general terms). Then after that you can follow some of the samples here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming.html or use the tutorials on the same site.

Comment: I downloaded MySQL Installer, but did,'t find any clear tutorial saying what I need to add as a reference to my project.. 
Is it the Database file ( .mdf ) that was created that I need to add ?

Thanks for the help by the way, I'm moving forward with this discussion.

Comment: .mdf is not a MySQL database. That's a Microsoft SQL Server Express database file. Did you install the actual MySQL server software onto your computer? If you're using SQL Server Express instead then you don't need any of the code or links I just provided. It helps to be clear about the tools and products you are actually trying to use.

Comment: I installed what you sent me, and now I have the MySQL Toolbar in my Visual Studio.Then, I connected Visual Studio to my Database ( I have the localhost connected, and I did find my database that was on PHP MyAdmin ). Now I need to use my database in my code.

Comment: ok so you do have mySQL itself installed, as well as the tools. So now you need to write some code like those tutorials to access your data. If you try to write something and can't get it to work, post it here along with any error messages and we can try and debug it.

Comment: Now it's ok, I managed to write a class in which I connect to my database, and I also wrote a function to add something in my database.
But the problem is that my class Program.cs doesn't find my class db.cs, but they are in the same Project.
I checked my solution on the right, and I can't see db.cs.
Did I create it somewhere wrong ? 
When I check to path of db.cs, it's in my project..

Comment: EDIT : This problem is solved. I managed to make it appear in my solution. 
But in the Program.cs, I still can't write db.AddData(); ( db.cs is the class where I wrote the function to add values )

Sorry for double post, could not Edit...